# Why does GitHub search not show the people I follow at the top of the search results?

Tags: github, search

For example, I follow Jeroen but his name does not show up at the top of the results. Any idea what could be the reason? And possible solutions?

[Refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRVFS.png)

Comment: That would be a question for GitHub. We have no way of knowing why employees of a commercial entity made a particular decision, which is one reason [we can't answer customer service questions here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/354577).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a customer service question.